# Javascript code is not working which supposed to add item inside list

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Event Listener</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1>Testing Event Listener</h1><br>
   <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Elements">
   <button id="enter">Enter</button>
   <ul>
       <li>Javascript</li>
       <li>Python</li>
       <li>Ruby On Rails</li>
   </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript code :

```
var input= document.getElementById("userinput");
var button= document.getElementById("enter");
var ul= document.querySelector("ul");
function inputLenght(){
    return input.value.lenght;
}
function creatListElement(){
    var li=document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));    
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value="";
}
function addListAfterClick(){
    if(inputLenght> 0){
        creatListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click",addListAfterClick);
```

This program is not showing any error but it is supposed to add item inside `<ul>` and a `<li>` that we write inside placeholder but it is not doing any thing

Comment: If you recived a solution in one of answers below - please mark it as correct answer. Otherwise please specify where you have more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input= document.getElementById("userinput");
var button= document.getElementById("enter");
var ul= document.querySelector("ul");
function inputLenght(){
    return input.value.length; // spelt length wrong here
}
function creatListElement(){
    var li=document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = input.value;    
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value="";
}
function addListAfterClick(){
    if(inputLenght() > 0){ //Missing brackets from "inputLength"
        creatListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click",addListAfterClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Event Listener</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1>Testing Event Listener</h1><br>
   <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Elements">
   <button id="enter">Enter</button>
   <ul>
       <li>Javascript</li>
       <li>Python</li>
       <li>Ruby On Rails</li>
   </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `inputLenght` in `addListAfterClick()`, and return `input.value.length;` instead of `input.value.lenght;` in `inputLength()`

```
var input= document.getElementById("userinput");
var button= document.getElementById("enter");
var ul= document.querySelector("ul");
function inputLenght(){
    return input.value.length; // <- typo here
}
function creatListElement(){
    var li=document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));    
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value="";
  console.log('foo')
}
function addListAfterClick() {
    if(inputLenght()> 0){ // <- need to call inputLength()
        creatListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your JavaScript:

`return input.value.lenght;`

Should be:

`function inputLenght(){
    return input.value.length;
}`.

Also need to call the function in your handler:

`inputLength()`

Comment: The title of the function should also be 'inputLength', but you call the name consistently with the typo so isn't a problem there

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because in `addListAfterClick` you are checking

`if(inputLenght > 0){`

instead of

`if(inputLenght() > 0){`

You are not calling the function, you are checking "if function if greater than zero", which is always `false`.

To test this - define `function f1() {}` in console and then run `f1 > 0`.

--- edit ---

Btw - a better name of this function would be `getInputLength`, so you know that you'll get some return value, and there's no typo in it (`ght` `->` `gth`)